# there are some issues in this family tree I made

Tags: html, css, tree, family-tree

> I have this good family tree but the problem is that the page is funcy like everything is on top of each other how can I fix it **(it's better to try it in a coding app because CSS doesn't work here (if it does I don't know))**
>
> ```
> <meta charset="UTF-8">
> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
> <title>family tree</title>
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
> <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
> ```
>
> rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
>
> - great great great grand father
>
>   - great great grand father
>
>     - great grand father
>
>       - grand mother
>
>         - grand father
>
>           mother
>
>           father
>
>           child
>
>           child
>
>           child
>
>           child
>
>           child
>
>           child
>       - father
>
>         mother
>     - child
>     - child
>     - child
>     - child
>     - child
>   - father
>   - mother
>
>     child
>
>     child
> - grand father
>
> grand mother
>
> ```
>                                         </li>
>                                     </ul>
>                                 </li>
>                             </ul>
>                         </li>
>                     </ul>
>                 </li>
>                 <li>
>                     <a href="#">father</a>
>                     <ul>
>                         <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
>                         <li>
>                             <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
>                             <ul>
>                                 <li>
>                                     <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
>                                 </li>
>                                 <li>
>                                     <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
>                                 </li>
>                                 <li>
>                                     <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
>                                 </li>
>                             </ul>
>                         </li>
>                         <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
>                     </ul>
>                 </li>
>             </ul>
>         </li>
>     </ul>
> </div>
>     </div>
> </div> </body> </html>
> ```

```css
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .tree ul {
        padding-top: 20px;
        position: relative;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    
    .tree li {
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        list-style-type: none;
        position: relative;
        padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    
    .tree li::before,
    .tree li::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 50%;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        width: 50%;
        height:
            20px;
    }
    
    .tree li::after {
        right: auto;
        left: 50%;
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    
    .tree li:only-child::after,
    .tree li:only-child::before {
        display:
            none;
    }
    
    .tree li:only-child {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
    
    .tree li:first-child::before,
    .tree li:last-child::after {
        border: 0 none;
    }
    
    .tree li:last-child::before {
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    }
    
    .tree li:first-child::after {
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    }
    
    .tree ul ul::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left:
            50%;
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
        width: 0;
        height: 20px;
    }
    
    .tree li a {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #666;
        font-family: arial, verdana,
            tahoma;
        font-size: 11px;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius:
            5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    
    .tree li a:hover,
    .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
        background: #c8e4f8;
        color: #000;
        border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
    }
    
    .tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
    .tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
    .tree li a:hover+ul::before,
    .tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
        border-color:
            #94a0b4;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Mermaid JS](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/), to obtain a graph,
It may also be helpful to see the shape of the abstraction used to create the tree structure.

As you can see in code -mermaid code- section,
With a one-dimensional flat set, it is possible to express node connections.
<sub>(Since enlarging the graph makes no practical sense,
I did not choose to enlarge any further. A tree with two or three generations is sufficient.)</sub>

I hope all this gives an idea.

PS:
On the additional question in the comments, I've edited the answer.
When using Mermaid, using the syntax in the example code `--> 2 [ Aidem ]`,
You can use the same name on different nodes. For additional questions, reviewing and trying the documentation may get you closer to the answer.

```
graph TD

Root --> Liven
Root --> Aidem

Root --> Dimitri --> Oleg
Root --> Olga --> Oleg

Liven --> Milna
Aidem --> Milna
Milna --> Harmi

Oleg --> Harmi

Harmi --> 2[Aidem]
Mina  --> 2[Aidem]
Root --> Mina
```

[image]

Comment: it's good but I have multiple names that are the same and the program will think the name is the same as the first **(for example)** 
graph TD

sarah --> Liven --> sarah
sarah --> Aidem --> sarah

sarah --> Dimitri --> Oleg
sarah --> Olga --> Oleg

Liven --> Milna
Aidem --> Milna
Milna --> Harmi

Oleg --> Harmi

Comment: @GameProgrammer, 
I've updated the answer with annotation and example change. I hope it works for you.